# PowerShell container selection for UPSA

Tags: user-profile-service

I've run into an issue trying to be selective with the OUs that we allow synchronization from. The problem is that our primary user OU has several OUs inside it that I want to exclude, but they don't show up in the list because it's being truncated. Is there a way to increase the items displayed or do this exclusion with another tool like PowerShell?

Comment: Want to translate "OU" for all of those of us that are not you please?

Comment: OU = Organizational Unit, a standard active directory scoping unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control for selecting the OUs (organizational units in Active Directory) is hard coded to only display up-to 1000 items.  This is the limit you are running into.

There is no *official* way to do this with PowerShell, however there are a few examples on the web of how to accomplish it.  Here is one example: http://mosshater.blogspot.com/2010/10/powershell-add-active-directory.html